# How to get max row ID of a database record with duplicate data

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I want to get the ID of the last row inserted for *"kashif"*.

How can I do this in Java?

I have a database table with columns:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________
| id | name | card_number | cell_number |sms_verification|inserted_date_time|
```

`id` is set as the primary key with auto-increment.

Inserting data into the database via Java works - I have a class where I get input from the user, and in the same class, I'm making a connection to the database.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=RestApi;user=sa;password=coder182");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

String query = "insert into User_information(action_name, card_number , cell_number ,sms_verification ,  inserted_date_time)"
    + "values ('" + action_name + "','" + card_number + "', '" + cell_number + "' , '" + sms_verification
    + "', '" + now + "');";
statement.executeUpdate(query)
```

Inputs look like this:

1. `kashif,28028209,239203084,yes`
2. `abid,233000,6260616,no`
3. `kashif,28028209,239203084,yes`

Comment: Obiligatory [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) reference. Don't ever trust user inputs. Please use parameterized queries (aka [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) in Java land) instead of constructing your own queries so you can avoid people deleting your tables or stealing your data. Or both.

Answer (score 1):

I Think, you could write a query something like this:

`SELECT max(id) from <Table Name> where name = 'Kashif'`

Or

`SELECT id from <Table Name>  where name = 'Kashif' Order by id desc Limit 1`

Comment: @Wasif, use one of these queries to create a `Statement` or `PreparedStatement`, and call `executeQuery()` to get a `ResultSet` containing the ID.

Comment: @GreenhouseVeg thank you . 1st one give me the result that i was expecting

Answer (score 1):

Add `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` in your `executeUpdate` statement.

```java
Integer createdId = null;
int executeUpdate = createStatement.executeUpdate(insertSql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = createStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
    createdId = rs.getInt(1);
}
System.out.println(createdId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a design change in your table schema. Create one more row which keeps the record of `last_updated_time` and you can query based on this `key`.

```
last_updated_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This will make your life lot easier as the number of entries grows into a table.